# how to delete single data using delete operator in c++

Tags: c++

How to **delete single element of array** using dynamic memory allocation in c++?I just want to delete the element of the array from the single position.I used delete operator but it was not helpful.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please give code sample.

Comment: @NPN, use vector and functions, .at(id), .erase(id).

Comment: You can't individual elements don't have their own separate allocations. There are ways to erase an element from an array, but it will have the same size when done; you need to use a container like `std::vector` for different capabilities.

Comment: @nakiya how are you supposed to produce a code sample for something you don't know how to do? I found the question perfectly understandable.

Comment: @MarkRansom:... Ok fair enough. but in my experience, these sort of problems get cleared up at OP's end immediately when he tries to express his problem in code.

Answer (score 4):

The `delete` functionality only works with *whole* things that you've allocated with `new`. In other words, if you've allocated an entire array with `new`, you cannot `delete` a part of it. So, this would be okay:

```
auto x = new int[10];  // An array of ten things.
delete[] x;            // Delete the *entire* array.
```

but this would not:

```
delete &(x[7]);        // Try to delete the eight item.
```

---

Resizable arrays in C++ should generally be using `std::vector`, as per the following example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Create a vector: 11, 22, ... 99.

    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (auto i = 11; i <= 99; i += 11)
        vec.push_back(i);

    // Remove the fifth thru sixth, and third elements (55, 66, 33).

    vec.erase(vec.begin() + 4, vec.begin() + 6);
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + 2);

    // Output modified vector.

    for (auto val: vec)
        std::cout << val << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output of said program is, as expected:

```
11 22 44 77 88 99
```

(I deleted the groups in reverse order since, otherwise, deleting `33` would have *changed* the position of those following, obscuring the intent of the code).

---

It's actually *very* unusual to see naked `new` and `delete` calls in modern C++, you should almost *always* be preferring smart pointers or the collections (such as `vector`) in the standard library.